# What happens if I don't use the --Reintegrate option in Subversion 1.5?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge, reintegration

I thought I had figured out everything I needed to know about Subversion 1.5 and was happily merging between my feature branches and the trunk.

Then I realized I've not been doing what I thought I had.

I have not been using the --reintegrate parameter when merging back to the trunk from a feature branch.

Specifically I use TortoiseSVN 1.5.3 and I had always been choosing the 1st Merge option "Merge a range of revisions" without specifying a range.

This I understood to be correct when merging from the trunk to the branch but I also understood that I should have used the --reintegrate parameter when merging the other way.

Instead I have been choosing the 2st option when merging in either direction, obviously picking the opposing url in each case.

It did seem to process the correct files in each case...

**So what (if anything) have I screwed up ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2008/07/subversion-merg.html) explains what might go wrong, why `--reintegrate` was created, and what it actually does.

Merging from the feature branch back to trunk without using `--reintegrate` will most likely only have caused you some extra conflicts, as described in the [post](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2008/07/subversion-merg.html)

Comment: great answer... I wish I could award bonus rep for this :)

Comment: You should award those to Mark Phippard for writing the article really :-)

Comment: I've looked at the post before, but until I read this question and answer I didn't realize it provided the answer I was looking for. That's what I get for skimming. Thanks :)